# Send message button gets stuck and sends multiple messages

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a bit new to ios development.

I've created a messaging app following some tutorials, using swift and firebase.

I've recently encountered a bug, where sometimes, when I want to send a message: I would write my message, and then I would press send. The message would update on the realtime database, but the textfield would not clear, and the message would not show. I would then press the send button multiple times, and the same thing would happen. until eventually, all the messages would send at once.

I'm a little confused, is there something wrong with my code, or is this a firebase issue. is there any workaround?

```
 func handleSend() {
        if chattextfield.text?.characters.count != 0 {
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
            let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
            //is it there best thing to include the name inside of the message node
            let toId = user!.id!
            let fromId = (userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid")) as! String
            let timestamp: NSNumber = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
            let values = ["text": chattextfield.text!, "toId": toId, "fromId": fromId, "timestamp": timestamp]
            //        childRef.updateChildValues(values)

            childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                self.chattextfield.text = nil

                guard let toId = self.user?.id else {
                    return
                } //unwrap this carefully 8:43, later ...
                let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromId).child(toId)
                let specificMessages = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages received").child(toId).child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String)

                let messageId = childRef.key
                userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
                specificMessages.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
                let recipientUserMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(toId).child(fromId)
                recipientUserMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
            }



        }
```

Comment: It seems FIREBASE mechanism, in video, they mention about, when you're off-line (bad network), the message will be cached. When your network is good, it send the message to the database automatically.

Comment: the textfield would not clear because "self.chattextfield.text = nil"  is in asynchronous callback. It will clear as soon as the message is added into database.